# how to kill/cancel a database backup operation using query in sqlserver 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, database-administration

I run following query for taking database backup in sqlserver 2005

```
backup database testdb to disk = 'D:\testdb.bak'
```

I want to cancel this operation using sql query

What will be the query?

Note: 
I'm executing this query from C# application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identify the session making the backup.

```
SELECT session_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.[sql_handle]) pln
WHERE pln.[text] = 'backup database testdb to disk = ''D:\testdb.bak'''
```

Then kill the session. Replace `<session_id>` by the session_id returned from the above query.

```
KILL <session_id>
```